# Send email by razor

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a contact form on a html website that I want to send emails from using ajax. I would like a simple page (preferably razor) to send the email.

The send email page must be secured so that no one else can post messages to this page via their own forms (Im thinking about only allowing the web servers ip address to send emails?). It must also support sending email via gmail (must be able to use ssl & custom port numbers).

Here is the ajax to send my email:

```
$('#ajax-contact-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#ajax-contact-form').valid()) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendemail.cshtml',
            data: $('#ajax-contact-form').serialize(),
            error: function () { $('#EmailMessage').html("Error! Please try again."); }, //Failed
            success: function () { $('#EmailMessage').html("Email sent!"); } //Sent 
        });
    }
});
```

Has anyone got an example of a razor page that I can use to send the email?

Comment: Actually razor is a template language so you don't send emails using razor.

Comment: Try the `Postal` NuGet package. It does all you need (and more) in a very clean Razor fashion. The emails (HTML, text or both) are just views with any number of injected values. Very cool stuff. The email config for sending emails just goes in the web.config.

Comment: The tutorial here covers how to generate and send email in ASP.NET Web Pages: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/email-and-search/11-adding-email-to-your-web-site

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code has been very helpful for me in web forms , IMHO it will also work here

you need 3 parameters , `Email` : to whom email will be sent, `MailSubject` subject line of email, `MailBody` text or html that will be appering in the email.

```
public static bool SendMail(string Email, string MailSubject, string MailBody)
{
    bool isSent = false, isMailVIASSL = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerUseSsl"]);
string mailHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerAddress"].ToString(),
senderAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSenderUserName"].ToString(),
senderPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSenderPassword"].ToString();

int serverPort = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerPort"]);

MailMessage msgEmail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(senderAddress), new MailAddress(Email));
using (msgEmail)
{
    msgEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msgEmail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    msgEmail.Subject = MailSubject;
    msgEmail.Body = MailBody;

    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailHost))
    {
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = isMailVIASSL;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderAddress, senderPassword);
        smtp.Port = serverPort;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(msgEmail);
            isSent = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
return isSent;
```

}

This is the web.config part , you can always hardcode it if you want.

```
<!-- Mail Server Settings -->
<add key="MailServerAddress" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<add key="MailServerPort" value="25" />
<add key="MailServerSenderUserName" value="info@gmail.com" />
<add key="MailServerSenderPassword" value="info_pswd" />
<add key="MailServerUseSsl" value="True" />
```